# Why do "Relativistic Light Sails Need to Billow"?

Tags: interstellar-travel, engineering, solar-sail, structural-design

The University of Pennsylvania School of Engineering and Applied Science blogpost [How to Design a Sail that Won’t Tear or Melt on an Interstellar Voyage](https://blog.seas.upenn.edu/how-to-design-a-sail-that-wont-tear-or-melt-on-an-interstellar-voyage/)
 links to two new Nano Letters papers:

- Matthew F. Campbell et al. (2022) [Relativistic Light Sails Need to Billow](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.nanolett.1c03272) (available in [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.10849))
- John Brewer et al. (2022) [Multiscale Photonic Emissivity Engineering for Relativistic Lightsail Thermal Regulation](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.nanolett.1c03273) (available in [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.03558))

These describe some really detailed and thorough research and make for some excellent reading!

The abstract of the billowing paper begins:

> We argue that light sails that are rapidly accelerated to relativistic velocities by lasers must be significantly curved in order to reduce their mechanical stresses and avoid tears.

Generally people have assumed that solar sails will be nominally flat to maximize photon recoil.

**Question:** Why do "Relativistic Light Sails Need to Billow"? Why does this *unexpected and significant curvature* they propose reduce mechanical stresses and avoid tears in these molecularly-thin sails undergoing intense laser illumination and acceleration?

Answer (score 8):

The [Hoop stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_stress#Hoop_stress) is proportional to the radiation pressure but inversely proportional to the curvature of the sail. Allowing the sail to billow increases the curvature and reduces the tension in the sail material. There must be an interesting curvature-thickness tradeoff where sails with more billow have more area but can be made thinner.

Comment: @uhoh It's based on my own views of non-relativistic barrels of beer.  I must admit I didn't look at the papers :-(    I don't understand how 'relativistic' can be relevant to anything other than to shift the wavelength of the illumination - but it certainly makes the title sound more exciting!

Comment: Wikipedia's equation $$\sigma_{\theta} = \frac{f}{tl} $$ does look similar to their expression (first complete paragraph on page 3) $$\sigma_{curved} = \frac{P s_s}{t_f}$$ where $P$ is pressure, $s_s$ is the radius of curvature and $t_f$ is the thickness of the film, but their reference #44 is a book and I don't have that handy. Could this be the analog of hoop stress for a spherical cap?

Comment: Ah, see equation S59 in the [supplement](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/acs.nanolett.1c03272/suppl_file/nl1c03272_si_001.pdf) and its reference 25 Yes, spherical pressure vessel.

Comment: @uhoh Yes, the sphere formula appears in the Wikipedia article but in the section called "relation to internal pressure".  That billowing paper is quite interesting . . . now I finally look at it :-)

Comment: Ya, the supplement is so thorough, this looks like a real labor of love :-)

Comment: @ uhoh and Roger Wood  in addition to stresses in the main body of the sail the designers must also pay attention to the stresses and strains where the sail attaches to the craft. Billow (or loft) can also help with reducing stress concentration problems at attach points at sail perimeter, helping to reduce overall mass.

Comment: @BradV maybe a rotating sail to keep it stable and fairly flat without needing any rigid members?  Wonder what the stresses look like in a rotating solid disk?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here. With a cylinder or sphere 'gas pressure' is always perfectly normal to inner surface. With a laser or solar sail the incoming photon force could be very oblique to curved edges to a greatly billowed sail. About a rotating sail... interesting thought. In the past I've wondered about large rotating structures for 'gravity' on generational starships and tried to understand effect of gyroscopic precession on propulsion and navigation. Was always wondering about pros/cons of wheels/discs vs barrels/tubes vs 'outrigger' type shapes.

Comment: @BradV if it's perfectly reflecting, photon pressure is also perpendicular to the surface (equal incident and reflected angles) but the pressure goes as cos(theta).  So it would drop off towards the edges.  Apparently the tension in a rotating disk also drops off towards the edge.  It's messy because you probably have to assume some Young's modulus, but it would be interesting to do numerically.  This shows some formulae: https://amesweb.info/StructuralAnalysisBeams/Stresses-Rotating-Rings.aspx